# Join Product and OrderDetails Tables and add a calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables called `Products` and `OrderDetails`. I want to pull particular columns from each table using a join, but I want to also add a column that multiplies the quantity from the `OrderDetails` table times the `Price` on the `Products` table.

How do I add the calculated column?

So far I have the everything except the calculated column:

```
SELECT 
    OrderDetails.OrderID, OrderDetails.Quantity, 
    Products.ProductID, Products.Price
FROM
    OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN 
    Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID;
```

I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results (as markdown text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty straightforward. Try this;

```
SELECT OrderDetails.OrderID, 
       OrderDetails.Quantity, 
       Products.ProductID, 
       Products.Price, 
       (OrderDetails.Quantity * Products.Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add any valid calculation as a calculated column.

Follows is a clean solution with the best practices of table aliases and schema prefixes. Not need to complicate with CTEs or brackets.

```
SELECT
    od.OrderID, 
    od.Quantity, 
    p.ProductID, 
    p.Price, 
    od.Quantity * p.Price AS TotalPrice
FROM dbo.OrderDetails AS od
JOIN dbo.Products AS p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID;
```

Note: I have also assumed you can't have an OrderDetail record without a product, so an `INNER JOIN` seems to make more business sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a CTE to make an"inline view"

```
 WITH t AS (
    SELECT 
        OrderDetails.OrderID, 
        OrderDetails.Quantity, 
        Products.ProductID, 
        Products.Price
    FROM OrderDetails
    LEFT JOIN Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
)
SELECT 
    t.OrderID, 
    t.Quantity, 
    t.ProductID, 
    t.Price, 
    t.Quantity * t.Price AS total_price
FROM t;
```

Comment: nothing really, I just think it gives it better readability, but certainly just a personal preference of mine.